# How to insert Timestamp in scalewidget

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make this 01:42

[image]

I have tried:

```
Scale(a,label='Current',from_='00:00',to='02:00',tickinterval='02:00',resolution='00:01',orient=HORIZONTAL,sliderlength=26,length=300)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: I dont think the text on `Scale` can be changed

Comment: @CoolCloud is there any alternative widget that can be used as a scrollbar for an mp3 player

Comment: You will have to make your own, like Bryan just did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't change the format of the displayed value. You will have to create your own label instead of using the one built into the widget. You can do that by attaching a command to the widget, and having that command update the label.

Since you're trying to represent time, I recommend setting the `from` and `to` options to the number of seconds, which can easily be reformatted to minutes and seconds.

Here's a basic example of a custom class that uses a fixed label (ie: it stays centered) and displays the value as minutes:seconds.

[image: screenshot]

```
import tkinter as tk

class CustomScale(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        from_ = kwargs.pop("from_", 0)
        to = kwargs.pop("to", 120)
        orient = kwargs.pop("orient", "vertical")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.value_label = tk.Label(self, text="00:00")
        self.scale = tk.Scale(
            self, from_=from_, to=to, tickinterval=0,
            command=self.update_label, showvalue=False,
            orient=orient
        )
        self.value_label.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        self.scale.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    def update_label(self, value):
        value = int(value)
        minutes = value//60
        seconds = value%60

        self.value_label.configure(text=f"{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}")

root = tk.Tk()
scale = CustomScale(root, from_=0, to=120, orient="horizontal")

scale.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```